# Empty refreshable List as drop destination?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I have a SwiftUI `List` that should be `.refreshable()` and also be a `.dropDestination()`. While the List has items, I can drop them at a specific index like so:

```
List {
    ForEach(items) { item in
        ...
    }
    .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, index in
        handleUrlDrop(items, at: index)
    }
}
.refreshable {
    await loadNewItems()
}
```

What I'm struggling with is making it a `.dropDestination()` when being empty. This is what I've tried:

```
ZStack {
    if items.isEmpty {
        BackgroundPlaceholder()
            .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, _ in
                handleUrlDrop(items)
                return true
        }
    }
    List {
        ...
    }
    .refreshable {
        await loadNewItems()
    }
}
```

It works, but I can only drop onto the `BackgroundPlaceholder` and I can't refresh by swiping on it. I also tried `.allowsHitTesting(false)`, but that makes it not a drop destination anymore. Same goes for putting something like `Color.white.opacity(0.0001)` on top.

I could maybe put the `BackgroundPlaceholder` inside the list, but that means it scrolls, has list separation lines and I'd probably have to fill the entire height with something like `GeometryReader` which seems terrible. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) on the List? A tip:  you should avoid AnyView wherever possible. I would also advise you to release a minimal reproducible example like it is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can try the code ourselves.

Comment: Do you need the list to be completely empty? How about just showing a single row that says something like "drop something here!" when there are no items? Also, do you need the *entire list* to be droppable?

Comment: @MatBuompy thanks for the hint :) A "complete" example is certainly nice, but I think it's straightforward enough, it should be enough to reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding an overlay, you can just change what the list displays depending on whether there are items or not, i.e.

```
List {
    if !items.isEmpty {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            ...
        }
        .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, index in
            handleUrlDrop(items, at: index)
        }
    } else {
        // put a view that is a drop destination here
    }
}
```

If you want the whole list to be droppable, you can use a `ForEach` that only displays one row. The `ForEach` makes the whole list droppable.

```
// in the else branch...
ForEach(0..<1) { _ in
    // this is a completely invisible row
    Color.clear
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)

    // alternatively, consider using a ContentUnavailableView: 
    // ContentUnavailableView("Drop something here!", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down")
}
.dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, _ in
    handleUrlDrop(items)
}
```

IMO, using `ForEach` feels a bit abusive. If you don't need the whole list be droppable, I would just put a single row that is a `ContentUnavailableView` and only allow things to be dropped onto that row.

Comment: Thanks, works great :) I also added `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` to the color. The only issue with this is that I can drop the new item above the invisible one which gives haptic feedback and shows the separator line again, but that's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to avoid something like this, but it gets the job done:

```
struct RefreshableEmptyDropView: View {
    var onRefresh: () async -> Void
    var onDrop: (_ items: [URL], _ location: CGPoint) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Color.white.opacity(Double.leastNormalMagnitude)
                    .frame(
                        minWidth: geo.size.width,
                        minHeight: geo.size.height - 100 // some breathing room
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, location in
                        onDrop(items, location)
                        return true
                    }
            }
        }
        .refreshable {
            await onRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```

I added the `minHeight: geo.size.height - 100` to avoid issues with the `NavigationStack` around it, the scroll content was slightly too high otherwise.

Use it like this:

```
ZStack {
    if items.isEmpty {
        BackgroundPlaceholder()
        RefreshableEmptyDropView(
            onRefresh: {
                await loadNewItems()
            },
            onDrop: { items, _ in
                handleUrlDrop(items, at: 0)
            })
    } else {
        List {
            ...
        }
        .refreshable {
            await loadNewItems()
        }
    }
}
```